# Paragraph view reference?

Tags: nodes, 8

I am trying to meet the following requirement:

I want to create a node (custom content type) that contains only a paragraph reference.

I have the following paragraphs in my node

- Billboard (large image + Caption)
- Testmonial (slideshow sentences)
- Body
- **Here i want to display a view that contains news articles (nodes from the custom news content type)**
- Call to action

But i can't seem to do this properly?

I can create a block display for my view and attach it to the page by path, but then the view is located **below** my paragraphs, where I want the view to be **one of the paragraphs**, since there is a call to action that needs to be located below the view.

Anyone ever tried this?

All suggestions welcome!

*If you have a solution that does not use paragraphs, I am also happy to hear!*

Many thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
After some additional searching, it seems that for D7, this module seems to be capable of doing this: https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_views_formatter more information can be found here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2756315

Still no solution for D8 though...

Answer (score 3):

Using hook_entity_view, you can insert the view into the field's build array.

```
function mymodule_entity_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {

  if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == 'node' && $entity->bundle() == 'example_content_type' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    $node_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node');
    $index = 0;
    foreach($build['field_paragraph_field'] as $key => $value) {

      if (is_numeric($key) && $value['#paragraph']->bundle() == 'body') {
        $news_view = [
          '#type' => 'view',
          '#name' => 'my_news_feed',
          '#display_id' => 'block_1',
          '#arguments' => [$node_id],
        ];

        array_splice($build['field_paragraph_field'], $index + 1, 0, [$news_view]);

      }
      $index++;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Views Reference Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsreference) module. This module provides a new field type that allows you to reference a view display similar to an entity reference field. After installing the module create a new paragraph type with a viewsreference field. You now have a paragraph type that displays a view.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to acheive this with any module that can add a view as a field. Currently for D8:

- Display Suite
- Entity views attachment
- Viewfield
- Display fields

Answer (score 0):

I did this by adding a paragraph type that is one Entity reference field.

There is a tutorial here:
https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/drupal-8-how-reference-views-block-display-field/

It works great and takes paragraphs to the next level.